# Comparison of functions' return values in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

How to define a function that checks whether 2 functions return equal values in Scheme?

This is my current code but it errors!

```
(define (equal-value f1 f2)
  (define f1_result (lambda (x) (f1 x)))
  (define f2_result (lambda (x) (f2 x)))
  (if (equal? f1_result f2_result) true false) 
  )
```

Any idea about what's going wrong?

Comment: **Any idea about what's going wrong?** Did you get an error message?  Anything?

Answer (score 1):

Some problems:

- `x` is not defined. You need to either pass in `x` as a parameter, or define it elsewhere.
- Also, in your code, `f1_result` and `f2_result` are actually functions, and not values.

Fixing your code:

```lisp
(define (equal-value f1 f2 x)
    (define f1_result (f1 x))
    (define f2_result (f2 x))
    (equal? f1_result f2_result))
```

This can be further compressed:

```lisp
(define (equal-value f1 f2 x)
    (equal? (f1 x) (f2 x)))
```

Here is an example of its usage:

```lisp
; Defining two functions
(define func1 (lambda (x) (+ x 5)))
(define func2 (lambda (x) (* x 2)))

(equal-value func1 func2 3) ; will return #f
(equal-value func1 func2 5) ; will return #t
```

Moreover, you don't need a function call to do this; you can perform the equality check anywhere you want directly.